# Php, DOMXpath. Invalid item(x) return

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

Simple thing but... We have such php code

```
$oPath = new \DOMXPath($this->oHtmlProperty);
$oNode = $oPath->query('//div[@class="product-spec__body"]');

foreach ($oNode as $oNodeProperty) {
    $oListTitle = $oPath->query('h2[@class="title title_size_22"]', $oNodeProperty);

    // ### VARIANT 1 (error with message 'Trying to get property of non-object')

    // $aPropertyGroup = [
    //     'title' => $oListTitle->item(0)->textContent,
    //     'property' => []
    // ];

    // ### VARIANT 2

    foreach ($oListTitle as $oListTitleItem){
        $aPropertyGroup = [
             'title' => $oListTitleItem->textContent,
             'property' => []
        ];

        break; // we need only first item
   }

// ....
```

So main thing that `$oListTitle` has always `->item(0)` node and no more. When we try to get it we get error `with message 'Trying to get property of non-object'` but this node exist! When we do same thing but through iteration (return same node class as we call ->item(x)) we get what we need.

Can someone tell why? XD

ADDED:

$oListTitle is :

```
object(DOMNodeList)#340 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) }
```

ADDED:

`var_dump($oListTitle->item(0));` return this one

```
object(DOMElement)#338 (18) { ["tagName"]=> string(2) "h2" ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(2) "h2" ["nodeValue"]=> string(45) "ÐžÑÐ½Ð¾Ð²Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ…Ð°Ñ€Ð°ÐºÑ‚ÐµÑ€Ð¸ÑÑ‚Ð¸ÐºÐ¸" ["nodeType"]=> int(1) ["parentNode"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["nextSibling"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["attributes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["ownerDocument"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> string(2) "h2" ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(45) "ÐžÑÐ½Ð¾Ð²Ð½Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ…Ð°Ñ€Ð°ÐºÑ‚ÐµÑ€Ð¸ÑÑ‚Ð¸ÐºÐ¸" }
```

Another words not empty and exists.

Comment: Please add an example HTML to your question so that is possible to reproduce the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem using php 5.6.3/win32 and the following code (your code + some boilerplate)

```
<?php
$foo = new Foo;
var_export($foo->bar());

class Foo {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->oHtmlProperty = new DOMDocument;
        $this->oHtmlProperty->loadhtml('<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <div class="product-spec__body">
        <h2 class="title title_size_22">h2_1</h2>
        <h2 class="title title_size_22">h2_2</h2>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="product-spec__body">
        <h2 class="title title_size_22">h2_3</h2>
        <h2 class="title title_size_22">h2_4</h2>
    </div>
</body></html>');
    }

    public function bar() {
        $retval = array(); $aPropertyGroup = array();
        $oPath = new \DOMXPath($this->oHtmlProperty);
        $oNode = $oPath->query('//div[@class="product-spec__body"]');

        foreach ($oNode as $oNodeProperty) {
            $oListTitle = $oPath->query('h2[@class="title title_size_22"]', $oNodeProperty);
            // ### VARIANT 1 (error with message 'Trying to get property of non-object')
            if ( !is_object($oListTitle) ) die('$oListTitle is not an object');
            if ( ! ($oListTitle instanceof DOMNodeList) ) die('$oListTitle is not a DOMNodeList');
            if ( $oListTitle->length < 1 ) die('oListTitle->length < 1');
            $node = $oListTitle->item(0);
            if ( is_null($node) ) die('$node is NULL');
            if ( !is_object($node) ) die('$node is not an object');
            if ( ! ($node instanceof DOMNode) ) die('$node is not a DOMNode');

            $aPropertyGroup = [
                'title' => $oListTitle->item(0)->textContent,
                'property' => []
            ];

            if ( !empty($aPropertyGroup) ) {
                $retval[] = $aPropertyGroup;
                $aPropertyGroup = array();
            }
        } 

        return $retval;
    }
}
```

the output is

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'h2_1',
    'property' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'h2_3',
    'property' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
)
```

as expected.
But maybe [libxml_get_last_error()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-last-error.php) can tell you more....

Comment: You used second variant and it working - I know that. Question was about first variant. ^_^

Comment: Same thing when I uncomment variante 1. No errors, same output. Just inspect the return value of `$oListTitle->item(0)` before accessing `textContent`.

Comment: Added to top message.

Comment: Please provide an sscce, see http://sscce.org/   Easiest if you take my example and edit the constructor to provide example data that (also) causes the problem on your machine.

Comment: Changed example to reflect variant 1

Comment: Your code gives me `oListTitle->length < 1`! Why? In `foreach` I get node! (rly hate this nodes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71249/discussion-between-volkerk-and-user1954544).

Comment: Found solution. Your code helps we find changes in html I pasring. Last `h2` does not exist - that's why whole script gives me error on unexisting object. thnx.

Answer (score 1):

You have two expressions, so if the first match has multiple items. It is possible that the inner match has different results depending on the outer match. You only set a single variable, so if the desired result is in one of the outer matches it will fill the variable.

You did not provide the HTML, so it not possible to really reproduce the error.

But if you're are using `DOMNodelist::item()` you should always validate that the return value is a node.

Here are two possible optimizations:

1. Limit the result to the first node: 
   `h2[@class="title title_size_22"][1]`
2. Fetch the text content of the first node as string (works only with `DOMXPath::evaluate()`): 
   `string(h2[@class="title title_size_22"])`

Example

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <div class="product-spec__body">
        <h2 class="title title_size_22">h2_1</h2>
        <h2 class="title title_size_22">h2_2</h2>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="product-spec__body">
    </div>
</body></html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="product-spec__body"]') as $index => $spec) {
  echo "Run #", $index, "\n";
  // all h2 with the class
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('h2[@class="title title_size_22"]', $spec));
  // first h2 with the class
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('h2[@class="title title_size_22"][1]', $spec));
  // first h2 with the class as string
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(h2[@class="title title_size_22"])', $spec));
  echo "\n\n";
}
```

Output - Compare the results of the two runs:

```
Run #0
object(DOMNodeList)#9 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(2)
}
object(DOMNodeList)#8 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(1)
}
string(4) "h2_1"


Run #1
object(DOMNodeList)#8 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}
object(DOMNodeList)#8 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}
string(0) ""
```